# How do I save an image file from json string which contains the image file?

Tags: php, json

This is a bit confusing. I use w2ui framework as my user interface and it sends JSON string when it posts a form that contains a file input. Now the JSON string looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd":"save",
    "recid":0,
    "record":
    {
        "id":"2",
        "image":
        [
            {
                "name":"test.jpg",
                "type":"image/jpeg",
                "modified":"2016-04-03T15:54:12.638Z",
                "size":31216,
                "content":"very_long_content_string"
            }
        ]
    },
    "id":"2",
    "image":
    [
        {
            "name":"test.jpg",
            "type":"image/jpeg",
            "modified":"2016-04-03T15:54:12.638Z",
            "size":31216,
            "content":"very_long_content_string"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know why the information is redundant. The question is how do I somehow save the file inside the `image` array into my local disk?

Comment: Is it the binary string very_long_content_string?

Comment: Most likely it is base64 encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the JSON and use:

```
<?php
$base64string = very_long_content_string;
file_put_contents('img.png', base64_decode($base64string));

?>
```

Comment: Why "img.png"? And where is the JSON involved in this answer?

Comment: @axiac img.png was just an arbitrary name. it can be any file name. I have mentioned that parse the JSON first.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer. Answer was supposed to give a head start to op.